# How is an empty XML element represented?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<Person>
    <Name>Tom</Name>
    <Age/>
</Person>
```

Is the correct representation of the `Age` value the empty string, `''` or a null value, such as `NULL`, `None`, `nil`, etc. For example doing in python it gives `None`, but is this part of the standard or a serialization decision?

```
>>> repr(etree.fromstring('<Person><Name>Tom</Name><Age/></Person>')
        .xpath('/Person/Age')
        [0].text)
# 'None'
```

Comment: `None` is a Python way to say there's nothing

Comment: Right, so that's an example of it being a null value rather than empty string. I'm asking here if that's in the standard or just a python or lxml decision.

Comment: Your question makes no sense on its own. We know how an empty XML element is represented in XML. You're asking how it is represented in something other than XML, for example in Python ElementTree, in XDM, in DOM, or in something else.

Comment: @MichaelKay for an xpath how should it be returned then?

Comment: XPath in the abstract returns an empty element node. If the tree is represented using a particular representation such as DOM or ElementTree, then it will return whatever that tree model uses to represent an empty element node. If you then serialize the empty element node or convert it to (say) a native Python or Javascript object, then the result is going to vary from one XPath client to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the XML level, an empty element simply has no [content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-content).

In XPath 1.0, `/Person/Age/node()` returns an empty [*node-set*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-sets); in XPath 2.0+, an empty [*sequence*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-sequence).

The `None` in your Python example is an artifact of Python, not XML or XPath.  The `/Person/Age` XPath expression returns a Python list containing an `Age` element.  That the element's (Python) `.text` attribute has a value of `None` is about Python, not XML or XPath.